# If $x=\frac{(r-p)(s-q)}{(r-q)(s-p)}$, what is $\frac{(s-r)(q-p)}{(q-r)(s-p)}$ in terms of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x=\frac{(r-p)(s-q)}{(r-q)(s-p)}$,

$y=\frac{(s-r)(q-p)}{(q-r)(s-p)}$

I've been asked to rewrite y in terms of x.

I've tried guessing the solution and it is:
$1-x=y$

Is there a more concrete way of getting this solution except guessing?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by guessing?

Comment: Finding the solution by brute force

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: Well, I saw that negating the denominator in y, has the same denominator as x. So I got the -x. then wondered what I needed to do to it to transform it into y. So I expanded the numerator of y and x and compared them to see that I needed a 1. I was looking for a way to transform y directly into something in terms of x rather than just thinking about what it should be.

Comment: That's not brute force guessing...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel what is it called? Sorry, I'm not great with terminology :/.

Comment: That is merely finding some similarity, some pattern in what you have been given, and using this to derive something simpler. This is not "dumb"; it's what mathematics is all about.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) will give you some good ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I'd notice is that barring a sign change, $x$ and $y$ have the same denominator. Thus, adding $x$ to $y$:
$$x+y=\frac{(r-p)(s-q)}{(r-q)(s-p)}+\frac{(s-r)(q-p)}{(q-r)(s-p)}=\frac{(r-p)(s-q)-(s-r)(q-p)}{(r-q)(s-p)}$$
$$=\frac{rs-ps-rq+pq-(sq-rq-sp+rp)}{(r-q)(s-p)}$$
$$=\frac{rs+pq-sq-rp}{(r-q)(s-p)}$$
Now note that $(r-q)(s-p)=rs+pq-sq-rp$:
$$=1$$
Thus $x+y=1$ and $1-x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

In $x=\frac{(r-p)(s-q)}{(r-q)(s-p)}$ and $y=\frac{(s-r)(q-p)}{(q-r)(s-p)}$, denote:
$$x=\frac{ab}{cd}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}r-p=a\\ s-q=b\\ r-q=c\\ s-p=d\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}s-r=b-c\\ q-p=a-c\\ q-r=-c\\ s-p=d\end{cases} \Rightarrow y=\frac{(b-c)(a-c)}{-cd}=\\
\frac{ab-c(a+b-c)}{-cd}=-\frac{ab}{cd}+\frac{c(s-p)}{cd}=-x+1.$$